# Problems Targeting Proper jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, json, object

My test page is currently displaying :[Test Page](http://lalunesucree.com/test-reviews-page/) which is a good sign somethings displaying but its not displaying properly.
I have these jQuery Objects as so:

```
reviews: Array[3]
 0: Object
    excerpt: "Everything I have had here is insane. SO GOOD. I always get a tuna baguette. Normally, the bread on sandwiches is just what holds it together, but here it..."
    id: "yVT2R7JQ5WRgVXZ-LrnJhQ"
    rating: 5
    rating_image_large_url: "http://media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/static/20101216354709277/img/ico/stars/stars_large_5.png"
    rating_image_small_url: "http://media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/static/201012161949604803/img/ico/stars/stars_small_5.png"
    rating_image_url: "http://media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/static/201012162578611207/img/ico/stars/stars_5.png"
    time_created: 1323827891
    user: Object
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
```

I want it to only show one "44 reviews from Yelp.com" Not 10... and I cant figure out how to properly get in to this object tree and target the right elements. Im using this script to display them with this script but i can't figure out why it is not displaying properly?

### This is the Script:

```
function showData(data) { 
 $.each(data.name, function(i,business){ 
 // extra loop 
 var bizContent = '<p><img src="' + data.rating_img_url + '" img=""/><br><a href="'+ data.url +'">'+ data.review_count + ' reviews from Yelp.com</a></p>'; 
 $(bizContent).appendTo('#yelpAVG'); 
       $.each(data.reviews, function(i,review){ 
         var content = '<div class="comments-block"><p>Posted by <a href="'+review.user_url+'">' +review.user_name + ' </a> on ' + review.date + 'via <a href="'+review.url+'">Yelp.com</a>'; 
         content += '<img src="' + review.user_photo_url + '" img=""/>'; 
         content += '<p><img src="' + review.rating_img_url + '" img=""/><br>'; 
         content += review.text_excerpt + '</p>'; 
         content += '<p><a href="'+review.url + '">Read the full review</a><br>'; 
         $(content).appendTo('#yelpReviews'); 
          }); 
    }); 
};
```

**Any Help or Direction is APPRECIATED!!!!**
Thanks For Reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `bizContent` append out of the loop:

```
function showData(data) {
    var bizContent = '<p><img src="' + data.rating_img_url + '" img=""/><br><a href="' + data.url + '">' + data.review_count + ' reviews from Yelp.com</a></p>';
    $(bizContent).appendTo('#yelpAVG');
    $.each(data.name, function(i, business) {
         // extra loop 
        $.each(data.reviews, function(i, review) {
            var content = '<div class="comments-block"><p>Posted by <a href="' + review.user_url + '">' + review.user_name + ' </a> on ' + review.date + 'via <a href="' + review.url + '">Yelp.com</a>';
            content += '<img src="' + review.user_photo_url + '" img=""/>';
            content += '<p><img src="' + review.rating_img_url + '" img=""/><br>';
            content += review.text_excerpt + '</p>';
            content += '<p><a href="' + review.url + '">Read the full review</a><br>';
            $(content).appendTo('#yelpReviews');
        });
    });
};
```

I'm not sure if you really need the first loop.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That fixed that problem but would you know why its showing "undefined" for the reviews? I cant figure out what the proper key or object im supposed to call or target